# Kerning Issue with the alphabet 'n' on site

Tags: css

There seems to be an issue when viewing a site in Firefox, non-bolded 'n' have a lot of space after.  Is there something that can be done for this?Attached is the screen shot of the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMd0.png)

Please help,i'm new to css and bootstrap as such,hence not able to move forward.

Comment: It looks like the font renders that way. Look at the space after the 'n' in Application. Do you have a screenshot of it in Chrome, or from a different OS?

Comment: This issue was not present in chrome.Will check the other words.I don't have the screenshot from chrome.sorry.not able to access it now.

Comment: There is a space after the 'n' in application.

Comment: Well it might be an issue with the font because this doesn't have anything to do with Bootstrap.